# How to do a rolling restart of daemonset in K8

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, daemonset

I have a K8 cluster with daemonset. In the daemonset manifest, the container image is configured with `<image_name>:latest` . How can I do a rolling update of my daemonset when I have a new image in the image_registry.

I know that if the image version is used, I could have changed the image version and K8 will do a rolling restart with

`kubectl edit ds/<my_dn_name> -n my_ns`

In my case, I am using `:latest`. so there is no change for me to do in the manifest file.

I can delete the daemonset pod, so that it will get re-created with new image. But I am looking for rolling restart/update option

`updateStrategy.type` is configured as "RollingUpdate"

Comment: Using a fixed `:latest` tag can be problematic in Kubernetes, for pretty much exactly this reason.  Can you use a unique image tag for each build, maybe using a source control commit ID or a date stamp for the version?  That resolves this ambiguity, makes it clear which version you're actually using, avoids some problems with unexpected upgrades, and it makes it possible to downgrade if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `imagePullPolicy: Always` in your pod spec.
using `kubectl edit ds my-ds`

or

```
kubectl patch ds my-ds -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec":{"containers":[{"name": "xxxxxxx", "imagePullPolicy":"Always"}]}}}}'
```

then you can use:

`kubectl rollout restart ds my-ds`

and use

`kubectl rollout status ds my-ds` to watch the procedure.